# System cannot run binary file - "no such file or directory"

Tags: 14.04, root, executable, binary

My problem is that my Ubuntu 14.04 can't run executable files even if they exist.
I have arm-none-eabi toolchain downloaded and I wanted to run some executable files with `./` but terminal says "no such file or directory". Then I tried as root user, also nothing. I have added this directory to my path, and it is still nothing.
I have no idea what can it be...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is the executable binary-compatible with your system? Or are you trying to run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system for example?

Comment: Oh... You may be right! I'm using 64-bit system and I'm not sure if that executable is too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple explanations for what might be going on:

1. You are in the wrong directory. Check by using `ls` and to find the full path use `pwd`
2. The permissions on the file do not allow the program to be an executable. Check with `ls -la` then the file permissions should have **-rwxrwxrwx** in some form where if they are not there then there will be a **-** in it's place. Change it with `chmod 775 <BinaryNameHERE>`

Check these two possible solutions and also please provide more detail so we can work through your problem.

Comment: So. My permissions look like this: "-rwxr-xr-x". And yes, I'm in good directory. I tried "chmod 755" and it still can't see it.

Comment: Arm toolchain's readme says "For 64 bit system, 32 bit libc and libncurses are required to run the tools." maybe that is a problem? If so, how can I install those libraries? I can see a lots of versions in synaptic.

Comment: Generally unless the program is bleeding edge I'd advise to use libncurses5-dev but probably run `sudo aptitude install libncurses5 libc6-i386` I believe the last package is the one you want. Can you provide me with the README install file?

Comment: [README](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/186123405/readme.txt) I think it works now. Tell me if there's anything else you want to warn me about. Anyway thenk's for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that you compiled without linking in a dynamic linker. The linker does not link a dynamic linker by default. Perhaps you needed one.

For more information see,

- [Unix Stack Exchange, *Running a custom-compiled executable returns “No such file or directory”*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472653/3285)